# How can I add the mean of body mass in my plot?

Tags: r

I am using the palmer penguins package and I created a plot. I would like to add a red line (the mean of body_mass) to the plot but can't find out what am I doing wrong?

```
attach(napenguins)


  plot(flipper_length_mm,body_mass_g,type = "h", lwd=2, las=1, 
       col="#527f85",
       xlab = "Flipperlengte",
       ylab = "Lichaamsgewicht",
       main = "Lichaamsgewicht ten opzichte van Flipperlengte",
       gemiddelde_lichaamsgewicht <- mean(napenguins$body_mass_g),
       
       abline (h= gemiddelde_lichaamsgewicht, col = "red")
       
      )
```

Error in R says:

> Error in int_abline(a = a, b = b, h = h, v = v, untf = untf, ...) :
> plot.new has not been called yet

Comment: The abline() command is called within your plot()-command - you probably just misplaced the last bracket...
Also, the calculation of the mean is within the plotting-command, which does not work this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following code

```
library(palmerpenguins)
data(package = 'palmerpenguins')
head(penguins)

plot(penguins$flipper_length_mm,penguins$body_mass_g,type = "h", lwd=2, las=1, 
     col="#527f85",
     xlab = "Flipperlengte",
     ylab = "Lichaamsgewicht",
     main = "Lichaamsgewicht ten opzichte van Flipperlengte")

gemiddelde_lichaamsgewicht <- mean(penguins$body_mass_g, na.rm = T)
     
abline (h= gemiddelde_lichaamsgewicht, col = "red")
```

[image]